# Visual Studio VB.Net RichTextBox control - text in columns have missing line breaks but tables work fine

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, richtextbox, rtf

Having problems with the RichTextBox VB.Net control in:
* Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5
* Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50938

I have RTF strings stored in a database & am using them in a RichTextBox, however:
* text within columns is missing the line breaks (aka hard returns/new lines/carriage returns). (eg: MS Word > Page Layout > Columns > type text & hit the Enter key).
* text within tables looks fine though & all other formatting that I have come across so far.

If I save the RTF string from the database into a *.rtf file & open it in Microsoft Word it displays the columns properly, however if I open it in WordPad the line breaks are missing from the columns, presumably as you can't create columns in WordPad, only in MS Word.

Ideas/solutions please?

Even if I could create a word document using the RTF string from the database, that should work, however I'm not sure how to do that:

Extract:

```
Private Sub RtfToWordDoc()

    ' Connect to database
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim oWord As New Word.Application

    ' prepare the sql query
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "select ... from ... where ..."
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon

    ' obtain the query results
    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    sqlReader.Read()

    If sqlReader.HasRows Then

        ' Populate the RichTextBox control on the Form with Query Results 
        Me.richTextBoxEx1.Rtf = CStr(sqlReader.GetSqlString(1))

        ' Copy the rich text box content
        richTextBoxEx1.SelectionStart = 0
        richTextBoxEx1.SelectionLength = richTextBoxEx1.TextLength
        richTextBoxEx1.Copy()

        ' Create a word document & paste the rich text box content into it
        oWord.Documents.Add()
        oWord.Visible = True
        Dim range = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
        range.Paste()   ' keeps RTB formatting, ignores word formatting

    Else
        MsgBox("No results found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End If

    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like the first thing you need to do is make sure WordPad supports what you want. Try creating the columns with "line breaks" (whatever is meant by that) in WordPad. If you can do it, then compare that to what your project is generating and see how they differ.

Comment: You can't do it in wordpad, only in word. In word you can create columns & add text with hard returns (aka line breaks/new lines/carriage returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out :)

```
Private Sub RtfToWordDoc()

    ' Connect to database
    Dim sqlCon As New SqlConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim sRTF As String
    Dim oWord As New Word.Application

    ' prepare the sql query
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "select ... from ... where ..."
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon

    ' obtain the query results
    sqlCon.Open()
    sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
    sqlReader.Read()

    If sqlReader.HasRows Then

        sRTF = CStr(sqlReader.GetSqlString(1))

        ' Populate the RichTextBox control on the Form with Query Results 
        ' Note: formatting within columns is incorrectly displayed
        Me.richTextBoxEx1.Rtf = sRTF

        ' Copy the contents of the Rich Text string to the clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(sRTF, TextDataFormat.Rtf)

        ' Create a word document & paste the rich text box content into it
        oWord.Documents.Add()       ' creates a new word doc using default word template (normal.dot)
        oWord.Visible = True
        Dim range = oWord.ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
        range.Paste()   ' keeps rich text formatting, ignores word formatting

        ' Change the single spacing (from normal.dot word template) to no spacing
        range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 1
        range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceAtLeast
        range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
        range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0

    Else
        MsgBox("No results found.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
    End If

    sqlCon.Close()

End Sub
```